# How to create multiple files for user input on a textfield jframe

Tags: java

I want to create different files everytime the user writes on the textfield but whith this code the user input goes always to the file question6.txt, rewriting what is there. I want to create files question6.txt, question7.txt, etc, everytime the user writes its input on the textfield. The name of the textfield is per, the query is about inserting input on a table that i have on DB.

```
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1, per.getText());
        int i=6;
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\marta\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\sqlteste\\Teste Formato (1)\\Teste Formato\\questions\\question"+i+".txt");
        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(writer);
        per.write(bw);
        bw.close();


        per.setText("");
        per.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the variable 'i' in creating the file name. And its value is hardcoded to 6. if you want to rename the file as you mentioned in the OP, move the variable outside the method and increment its value every time you write data out to a file.

you will have to see whether to set it as static or not, depending on how this code is being called.